# Acortar uRL con split - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, split, cli

su ayuda por favor tengo que mostar una imagen depende del path o url, ya lo he conseguido pero quisiera mejorar el path para que quede de esta manera `this.router.url === /categoria/`, me sugieren usar split pero no he conseguido acortar las url, para solo tener un path apuntando a /categoria/ y eliminar las rutas siguientes alguna idea Muchas Gracias.

```js
if (
      this.router.url === "/" ||
      this.router.url === "/categoria/cuidado-personal" ||
      this.router.url === "/categoria/mam%C3%A1-y-beb%C3%A9" ||
      this.router.url === "/categoria/salud" ||
      this.router.url === "/categoria/bienestar" ||
      this.router.url === "/categoria/nutrici%C3%B3n-adulto"
    ) {
      this.cintilloHome = true;
    } else {
      this.cintilloHome = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el split para dividir cada “/” y tendrás un array, como esperas que categoría este en la primera sección puedes revisar la posición 1 dentro del array que te regresara.

```js
    if (
      this.router.url === "/" ||
      this.router.url.split(“/”)[1] === “categoria”
    ) {
      this.cintilloHome = true;
    } else {
      this.cintilloHome = false;
    }
  }
```